# Loading a JSON list in HTML using class and other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have successfully managed to create an HTML list from JSON data using the following...

```
function loadList() {        
    $.getJSON( "http://www.JSONURLDATA/TEST", function(Cust) {
    var ul = $('<ul>').appendTo('#custList');
    for(var i = 0; i < Cust.Customers.length; i++) {
        ul.append($(document.createElement('li')).text('(' + Cust.Customers[i].Keycode + ') ' + Cust.Customers[i].Name));
        console.log(Cust.Customers[i].Name);
    }
    })

}
```

This displays and works well. I would like to build on this however and use the ionic css to display the information better and also add an image. Full info can be found [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#item-avatars), but it basically just formats the HTML like this...

```
<div class="list">

<a class="item item-avatar" href="#">
  <img src="venkman.jpg">
  <h2>Venkman</h2>
  <p>Back off, man. I'm a scientist.</p>
</a>

...
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to build on the dynamically generated list and add other elements please? The JSON returned has image url I could use, as well as info to put in the

.

Comment: Can you show us how your JSON is structured? You need to modify your `ul.append()` to accommodate for this.